# Tuples vs lists for module-level constants in Python?

Tags: python, list, coding-style, tuples, immutability

Is it good style to use tuples rather than lists for module-level constant iterables in Python? For example, I have a list of important strings at the top of my file that I need to look for in my input:

```
IMPORTANT_STRINGS = [
  "Hello world!",
  "Goodbye world!",
  "Foo...",
  # etc --- there are about 40 entries
]
```

`IMPORTANT_STRINGS` will never be modified while my program is running.

On the one hand, I think that immutability is good and that I should prefer immutable data structures whenever possible, so I should use a tuple instead.

On the other hand, I think that tuples are more than just immutable lists: they're for heterogenous collections that should be used when you're passing around things like pairs, triples, etc --- fixed-size things whose size is important to what they are. I also don't think that I've ever seen Python code in the wild that uses tuples for constants like this, and it looks really strange to my eye to say:

```
IMPORTANT_STRINGS = (
   "Hello world!",
   etc
 )
```

Comment: constant implies immutability so I personally would use a tuple ... that said im pretty sure there is no "best practice" defined for this so use whichever you like more

Comment: Why are you grouping these together in any sort of structure at all? Will you ever be iterating over them? Will you ever be accessing them by index (and if so, is that really the best way of getting at them?) Why are you defining string constants at all? Long collections of string constants in general just seem like a bad code smell to me, where what you really want would be some kind of attribute on an object, or keyword arguments instead. It tends to be a symptom of [stringly typed code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped).

Comment: Regarding hererogenous - lists should consist of all objects of the same type. Tuples have no such restrictions - they may or may not have objects of different types. But since your variable is called `IMPORTANT_STRINGS`, I think it's already pretty clear to the user that whatever the type of the collection is, the values within are of type `string`.

Comment: Yes, I loop over them later on. There are good reasons in the rest of the code to define this variable, the question is what type it should have. I see the appeal of using an immutable data structure but I don't think I've ever seen tuples used like that in the wild, so it feels strange to me.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The variable not actually called "IMPORTANT_STRINGS" in the code, I've scrubbed the details from it for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a module, call it foo.py and insert the following:

```
FOO = 'a', 'b'
BAR = ['a', 'b']
```

Now import them and see how they respond to in-place operations:

```
>>> import foo
>>> from foo import FOO, BAR
>>> FOO += 'c', 'd'
>>> BAR += 'c', 'd'
>>> FOO
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> foo.FOO
('a', 'b')
>>> foo.BAR
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

As we can see, `FOO`, the tuple, remains in its original state as the canonical collection in the `foo` module. `BAR` on the other hand, can be mutated.

Which should you prefer?

It depends on what you want to happen when other modules access the collection. In many cases, we want other modules to be able to add to a canonical list. In some cases, we don't. The answer is to do what is appropriate given your circumstances and purposes and intentions for design and use.

In your case, you say:

> IMPORTANT STRINGS will never be modified while my program is running.

If they never *should* be modified, then tuples are fine. If you want your code to be useful to others who may need to share data in the same process, then you should go with a list.

You mention:

> I think that tuples are more than just immutable lists: they're for heterogenous collections that should be used when you're passing around things like pairs, triples, etc --- fixed-size things whose size is important to what they are.

Tuples are essentially immutable lists, and lists can have all kinds of objects in them too. Yes, fixed size, but that's really just a direct result from the immutability.

Should you use tuples as immutable lists? I wouldn't. I would use lists on the theory that users of my code are responsible, and can handle modifying lists from modules they didn't write.

Note that the ability of lists to be extended with tuples as demonstrated above means that you can generally start with tuples and then move to lists as needed.

Comment: I understand the difference between mutable and immutable data structures and why I should prefer immutable ones. I'm just weirded out because I've never seen python written like this --- if I only used lists when I needed mutability, I would use tuples in place of about 80% of the collections I currently use. Do you actually write code that is almost entirely filled with tuples, using lists only when absolutely necessary?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I do find myself using tuples more than other Python coders (who seem to treat lists as the only kind of Python "array"). I make use of Python's duck-typing and abstract base class checking, so if I need to start using a list instead, it doesn't break my code to switch.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is the most complete, but I'd like to note that I find it unsatisfying. I have never seen any code in the wild that uses tuples over lists in this case and I still think it is stylistically very strange. I can imagine Python that consistently uses tuples over lists and I think it would be fine, but unless you are working on your own personal project, I think this is going to clash with the expectations of the other developers on your team. Immutability is important and it is great in languages that support it well, but imo this is not Pythonic.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for the tuple. Tuples are faster, immutable and - cause of this - more secure. Why do you want a mutable type for something that should be immutable?

The argument that "tuples are for heterogenous collections" has no sense to me. Lists can store heterogenous elements too. The assumption that tuples = heterogeneous and lists = homogeneous is just a generalization, usually you want a list to iterate through elements and work with them similarly (If not exactly in the same way at least in a polymorphic way)

Tuples on the other hand are slightly similar to a struct in the sense that are used to store values that have some relation in the model you're coding and in this way are related to heterogeneous elements, but why can't them be the same type? For example a 3 dimensional vector would be represented as a tuple (At least is the most intuitive way) but it's composed just by 3 numbers, should we use a list just cause they're the same?

Comment: I think I hit heterogenous harder than I should, but vectors are different --- the fact that they are N dimensional is an intrinsic part of their type. It's significant that they have that structure. This, on the other hand, is just a collection of a few things that happens to be statically initialized rather than being built at runtime. I think about 80% of code is pure by accident and 99% can be trivially rewritten to be pure. I've never seen python code that uses tuples as the default kind of collection, do you write code like that?

Answer (score 1):

Just for a counter argument, `__all__` is a **list** of public objects that a module will export when: `from <module> import *` is used.

This is basically a collection of module-level, constant strings (like you have), but is implemented as a list throughout the standard library.  A quick test confirms that a `tuple` will work for this as well, yet everywhere it's a list.

Comment: It's mutability means you can extend modules in-place. From my experience in earlier Pythons, it must be a list to get the expected effects, but a quick check with Python 3 shows that it doesn't matter there.

Comment: Interesting...how do modules get extended in-place?

Comment: I'm using extend in the sense of adding to the API, although it's a simple matter to replace the `__all__` tuple instead of extending the list (which affects the names imported with `import *`), I don't see anyone ever using another module's `__all__` by importing the name directly.

Comment: @Aaron:  Yes, I agree it's possible, but doesn't seem (to me) like the most likely reason a list was chosen.  I'd guess that early on, someone used/picked a list for this, and it just kind of became an unwritten convention after.